# How to show loading spinner in GetBuilder

Tags: flutter, api, dart

In FutureBuilder when working with an API you can easily show loading spinner when data is not yet available with this code,

```
   if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                   );
                }
```

how do I do same for GetBuilder when using getx as state management library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic example of re-building based on the value of an `isLoading` bool. I'm just changing the value of a `String` but this should give you the idea of doing a proper API call in a GetX function and displaying an indicator. While I typically default to using `GetBuilder` whenever possible, showing loading indicators I generally just use `Obx` so I don't have to call `update()` twice.

```
class TestController extends GetxController {
  bool isLoading = false;

  String data = '';

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    isLoading = true;
    update(); // triggers the GetBuilder rebuild
    await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => data = 'Data Loaded',
    );
    isLoading = false;
    update();
  }
}
```

You can test this by throwing this in a `Column`. Just make sure the controller is initialized first at some point with `Get.put(TestController());`

```
            GetBuilder<TestController>(
                builder: (controller) => controller.isLoading
                    ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                    : Text(controller.data)),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => controller.fetchData(),
              child: Text('Fetch Data'),
            ),
```

If you don't want to have to manually call the function you can also lose the `isLoading` bool use a `FutureBuilder` but then just pass a `Future` function from a GetX class to keep that logic out of your UI.

## Update

Here's an example using live dummy data of random Kanye quotes from
https://api.kanye.rest Copy the code below into your IDE and run it and it should make sense.

Basic `ApiCaller` class

```
class ApiCaller extends GetConnect {
  final url = 'https://api.kanye.rest';
  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    final response = await httpClient.get(url);
    return response.body['quote'] as String;
  }
}
```

Updated `TestController` class

```
class TestController extends GetxController {
  String data = 'no data';
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<void> updateData() async {
    _updateIsLoading(true);
    final apiCaller = ApiCaller();
    await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => data = 'Data Loaded',
    ); // just to add more visible time with loading indicator
    data = await apiCaller.fetchData();
    _updateIsLoading(false);
  }

  void _updateIsLoading(bool currentStatus) {
    isLoading = currentStatus;
    update();
  }
}
```

Example with `GetBuilder` and `FutureBuilder`

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(TestController());
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                future: ApiCaller().fetchData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text('FutureBuilder: ${snapshot.data}');
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              ),
              GetBuilder<TestController>(
                builder: (_) => controller.isLoading
                    ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                    : Text('GetBuilder: ${controller.data}'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => controller.updateData(),
                child: Text('Update GetBuilder'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Example with FutureBuilder with function from GetX class

Comment: Please can i have a code illustration of what you are trying to explain here?

Comment: See updated answer